# API Gateway regional custom domain name not resolving

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I am attempting to take my API Gateway endpoint and map it to a custom regional domain name. Can someone help identify if I've made a mistake anywhere along the way? I've followed the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-regional-api-custom-domain-create.html) pretty faithfully but cannot pinpoint where I've gone wrong. I performed the following steps:

1. Used Route 53 to register a domain, let's say **`mydomainname.com`**.
2. Created a certificate through ACM with **`api.mydomainname.com`**, **`mydomainname.com`** and **`example.mydomainname.com`** included as CNAME records to the DNS configuration for my domain.
3. Created a custom domain name in API Gateway for my **`playground-api`** API with stage **`development`** (see below):

[image]

4. Using the **Target Domain Name** specified in the above image, went to my **Route 53 Result Record Sets** and added it in as a target:

[image]

When I attempt to access **GET `https://api.mydomainname.com`**, I get a **`CONNECTION REFUSED`** error. However, using the endpoint from the deployed stage (the endpoint provided after you deploy a stage) through API Gateway works perfectly.

The available endpoints I have exposed and deployed on API Gateway are **`GET /`**, **`PUT /widgets/`**, and **`GET /widgets/{id}`**.

I acknowledge there's been plenty of posts (like here, [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=269585&tstart=0), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306053/api-gateway-regional-custom-domain-is-not-working), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53881216/custom-domain-name-on-api-gateway-always-returns-403-forbidden-even-though-api-g)) on this topic, but it doesn't look like anyone has come to any good solutions yet. However, it appears the common theme in all of the posts so far are lack of enough details, so I hope perhaps my post contains enough information for more experienced SOers to help.

Comment: What is behind your API? Is it a Lambda function? Do you have logs of those invocations? The input to your integration be will slightly different when accessed via custom domain. Are you sure your integration (Lambda function?) is configured to deal with this difference?

Comment: @BobKinney. They are a mix of Lambda functions and direct API calls to a DynamoDB table. They were being called fine and there's logic inside the Lambdas to handle errors. Interestingly, when I checked this morning- hitting the exact same endpoints- they worked perfectly. Is there some sort of time lag in associating a custom domain name?

Comment: No, there should be no lag time.

Comment: @YuChen Did you manage to solve this? As I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @DeanLe see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58683733/1749888, it worked for me. Not sure about OPs case

Comment: Has there been any update? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Any resolution to this?