# API gateway LambdaRestApi custom domain gets ECONNREFUSED Error upon requests

Tags: python, certificate, aws-cdk, amazon-route53, api-gateway

I've looked at some other posts, but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306053/api-gateway-regional-custom-domain-is-not-working) is the closest question I could find that might be close to what I'm experiencing. I'm just not that clear on it from what was stated in the answer.

I'm creating an LambdaRestAPI through API gateway and attempting to use a route53 hosted zone to use as domain of my endpoint. I've created all of this using aws-cdk, which seems to work except when I am creating the alias record to connect to the custom domain of my api.

My aws-cdk code is shown below.

```
from aws_cdk import (
    Stack,
    aws_apigateway as apigateway,
    aws_lambda as lambda_,
    aws_iam as iam,
    aws_ecr as ecr,
    aws_route53 as route53,
    aws_route53_targets as targets,
    aws_certificatemanager as cman
)
from constructs import Construct


class ApiStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id,  **kwargs)

        repo_ = ecr.Repository.from_repository_arn(self,
                    'repo',
                    repository_arn=<image_arn>
                        
        tag_ = <image_tag>

        backend = lambda_.DockerImageFunction(self, 'myLambda',
                    code=lambda_.DockerImageCode.from_ecr(repository=repo_,
                                                          tag=tag_),
                    architecture=lambda_.Architecture.X86_64
                  )

        certificate = cman.Certificate.from_certificate_arn(self,
                                                            'cert', <cert ARN>
                                                            )

        api = apigateway.LambdaRestApi(self, "myAPI",
            handler=backend,
            proxy=False,
            endpoint_configuration=apigateway.EndpointConfiguration(
                                        types=[apigateway.EndpointType.REGIONAL]),
            domain_name=apigateway.DomainNameOptions(
                                    domain_name=<custom-domain-name>,
                                    certificate=certificate
    )
        )

        hosted_zone = route53.HostedZone.from_lookup(self, 'myHostedZone',
                                                domain_name=<hosted-zone-domain-name>)
                                                     )

        route53.ARecord(self, 'Arecord',
                        zone=hosted_zone,
                        target=route53.RecordTarget.from_alias(targets.ApiGateway(api)),
                        record_name=<domain-name>
                        )
```

When I hit the invoke url, everything works fine. However, when I try to hit the custom domain linked to my API or the route53 alias, I get `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED`

From the post I shared above, I think it might have something to do with HTTP vs HTTPS requests, but I don't feel like I know enough to explore that thoroughly.

Any ideas why I cannot hit my custom domain?

Comment: Some thoughts ...Does your certificate cover the subdomain you are using? and you have <custom-domain-name> and <domain-name> - are these the same value?

Comment: yes the certificate covers the subdomain. It really covers anything (*.example.com). The custom domain name and domain name are the same, but I have to declare them in each section. I guess I could clean that up in my code.

Comment: How are you invoking your api? what module are you using?  It is an http/https error indeed - I usually only see this when testing locally and I have to disable cert checks.

Comment: I'm invoking through the url provided by AWS API gateway, which is https.  https://<api-code>.execute-api.<aws-region>.amazonaws.com/<stage-name>. This works. It is when I am routing my route53 url to this invoke API that isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like everything was fine. I didn't know, but if you don't specify to use HTTPS in your domain, it will default to HTTP. So I was trying to call `http:a.example.com` when I should have been calling `https://a.example.com` API gateway doesn't support HTTP with custom domains.

All credit goes to the person that answered the question on this post.

[api gateway regional custom domain is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306053/api-gateway-regional-custom-domain-is-not-working/58683733#58683733)